# Find text and assign to a variable with VBscript

Tags: variables, search, vbscript

I have a program giving me output like below.

```
Listing 3 device(s) for setup class "Ports" (Ports (COM & LPT)).
USB\VID_067B&PID_2303\5&164808BA&0&3                        : Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM3)
USB\VID_068B&PID_2304\5&164808BA&0&3                        : Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM4)
USB\VID_069B&PID_2305\5&164808BA&0&3                        : Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM6)
```

I would like to get the COM# value out and assign it to a variable using vbscript
like so

```
P1=COM3
P2=COM4
P3=COM6
```

The persona this link http://vbcity.com/forums/t/154919.aspx is getting the output I want using the line.

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames
```

but I am not sure how to implement this in my script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your output and saved it in a text file called `OUTPUT.TXT`, so the command I'm using to run it is:

```
TYPE OUTPUT.TXT
```

However, feel free to replace `TYPE OUTPUT.TXT` with your actual program. The Following `VBScript` shows how to run this command and capture and parse the output in `VBScript`. I use `INSTR` and `MID` to locate and extract the substrings I need:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objExec
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("CMD /C TYPE OUTPUT.TXT")
Dim lines
lines = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll
Dim line
Dim P(10)
Dim num
num = 0
For Each line in split(lines, vbCrLf)
  Dim idx
  idx = InStr(line, "Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (")
  If idx > 0 Then
    idx = idx + 34
    Dim idx2
    idx2 = InStr(idx, line, ")")
    num = num + 1
    P(num) = Mid(line, idx, idx2 - idx)
    WScript.Echo "P" & num & "=" & P(num)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: This appears to work, I'll have to wait till I get home to see if it will work with multiple options.  Just out of curiosity, what is up with using Dim to note a variable in VBscript.  I've read that you're suppose to do it, but never noticed a difference if I don't.  Seems like it just adds clutter to the script.

Comment: `DIM` means dimension and, historically, was used to declare the size of arrays in `BASIC`. However, it's been re-purposed to declare any variable. It's just a matter of good practice, but, `VBScript` doesn't  enforce this practice by default. Generally, when, writing scripts, one should use `OPTION EXPLICIT` to enforce this behavior. This will trap typos. For example, in the script I wrote, if I mispelt any of my variables, the script would run incorrectly instead of raising an error.

Comment: So this works mostly, the problem is that I need to generate a variable to feed into the rest of the script, so instead of having a message box with P1=COM1, P2=COM2, I need it to write the variables P1=COM1.  I see that I can't put P(num)=PORT then extract this, after the loop.

Comment: If you come up with something that would be nice, in the mean time I just added an "if then" and put in a variable, since the user of the program is likely never going to have more than 3 COMS, this isn't a problem, but would be nice to know how to do this with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your other question on here. You should be able to get this from WMI from the Win32_SerialPort class. Does this help?

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/CIMV2" )
Set colInstances = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort" )

If colInstances.Count = 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "1 instance:" & vbCrLf
Else
    WScript.Echo colInstances.Count & " instances:" & vbCrLf
End If

For Each objInstance In colInstances
    WScript.Echo "Availability                : " & objInstance.Availability
    WScript.Echo "Binary                      : " & objInstance.Binary
    WScript.Echo "Capabilities                : " & Join( objInstance.Capabilities, "," )
    WScript.Echo "CapabilityDescriptions      : " & Join( objInstance.CapabilityDescriptions, "," )
    WScript.Echo "Caption                     : " & objInstance.Caption
    WScript.Echo "Description                 : " & objInstance.Description
    WScript.Echo "DeviceID                    : " & objInstance.DeviceID
    WScript.Echo "Name                        : " & objInstance.Name
    WScript.Echo "PNPDeviceID                 : " & objInstance.PNPDeviceID
    WScript.Echo "ProviderType                : " & objInstance.ProviderType
    WScript.Echo
Next
```

Comment: This script comes up with 0 instances.  I think the problem may be that the serial port is actually a USB>serial adapter, so it ma y not be listed under the WIN32_serialport.